# Project depedencies in Eclipse m2e multiproject vs. package with manifest

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am finishing migrating a standalone multi-project java from Ant to Maven. The structure of my projects is similar to the following:

```
parent-project
|_ Project A
|  |
|_Project B
|_Project C
```

In parent-project there is no code but I define in the DependencyManager the most common used dependencies and their versions. ProjectA POM uses the depedencies defines in parent-project and ProjectB too and calls methods from ProjectA.

I can perfectly execute my desktop application from Eclipse as a Maven project (Goals: exec:java). The Dependency Hierarchy tab provided by m2e shows the right dependency order and it's the same shown as dependency:build-classpath.

```
dependency:build-classpath tells Maven to output the path of the dependencies from the local repository in a classpath format to be used in java -cp. The classpath file may also be attached and installed/deployed along with the main artifact.
```

However, despite my project depedencies seems correct when I launch the standalone application as a Maven main project from Eclipse, it is not the same when I package the jar with its jar dependencies in a sub-directory (created with maven-jar-plugin).

```
MyApp.jar
|_ \lib
   |_ MyApp dependencies 
   |_ Maven projects jars
   |_ Maven projects jars dependencies
```

My manifest file include a classpath that is the equivalente to execute "mvn dependency:resolve" but I still don't manage to figure out where the order of these jars come from (even changing the POM doesn't seem to have any effect on it). My application manage to run but I have many problem with runtime libraries because it doesn't use the one that it is meant to use.

```
dependency:resolve tells Maven to resolve all dependencies and displays the version
```

If there is someone out there that could point out the source of this problem, I would be eternally greatful.

Comment: Could you be clearer in what you want to achieve? Are you trying to build a "fat jar" with all dependencies included, or do you want to reference them through a path?

Comment: I edited the question trying to give some more details. Thanks for getting interested.

Comment: Do you have jars with overlapping classes? Is this the reason you need a special order in the jars on the classpath?

Comment: Some dependencies include their own dependencies that could enter in conflict in runtime (ex: cxf, axis and jdk webservices).
But still, the mystery for me is this dependency:resolve order vs. dependency:build-classpath differences. This reflects on the result of my manifest and therefore the application dependencies once packaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found myself the solution after all.

The problem appeared only when invoking `maven-dependency-plugin` for copying the dependencies. I remove the execution of that plugin and replace the copy-resource with `maven-resources-plugin`.

**Before (not working):**

```
  <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format> 
    </formats>
    <!-- Dependencies properties -->
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <!-- To avoid include the target name as a root directory -->
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <!-- Copy resources from resources to target -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>../AnotherJavaProject/src/main/resources/utils/</directory>
            <outputDirectory>utils</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <!-- ...more resources here -->

        <!-- Copy the .exe to the target folder -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.exe</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**After (working):**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                    <!-- Copy resources from resources to target -->    <directory>../AnotherJavaProject/src/main/resources/utils/</directory>
                        <targetPath>utils</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <!-- ...more resources here -->

                    <!-- Copy the .exe to the target folder -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>*.exe</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope this help somebody.